# Generic Repository Pattern have repetition of code so what will be benefit?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I am understanding repository pattern in c#. I am confused when i study about generic repository pattern. There is lot of repetition in it. i have some question about this pattern.

I am using Entity Framework code first approach and i have two model classes

**Student**
**Teachers**

How many generic interface i will use for example if i have one
   generic interface

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
{
   IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null);

   TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null);       
}
```

So this interface can be use in both model classes.
if **Student** class have more methods where i can define these methods? for example

```
public class StudentRepo<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null)
    {
        return null != where ? Context.Set<TEntity>().Where(where) : Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null)
    {
        return FindAll(where).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void update()
    {
    }

    public int FindId()
    {
    }
}
```

So i have added two new methods `update()` and `FindId()` in `StudentRepo` where can I define these methods?

If I want to add these two methods in `IRepository` then I have to call these methods for Teacher class. what will be benefit of it?
Is this better approach if i create separate interface for both classes? like IStudent and ITeacher so i can define those methods which i want to use and unnecessary methods will not be in use.

Kindly guide me i am so confused.

Answer (score 6):

You can have one implementation for the `IRepository` that you have, something like:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> FindAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null)
    {
        // implementation ...
    }

    public virtual TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where = null)
    {
        // implementation
    }

    public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        // update your entity ...
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Then have your own repository inheriting from it:

```
public class StudentRepository : GenericRepository<Student>
{
    // here you get all the goodies + you can add your own stuff
}
```

And:

```
public class TeacherRepository : GenericRepository<Teacher>
{
    // here you get the same goodies, you don't need to re-implement them
}
```

This way you don't have to re-implement all the methods defined in the generic repository, you can however add your own more complex methods.

Comment: So what will be benefit GenericRepository class while i can use for just StudentRepository. if i creates separate interface IStudent for Student class it will be better?

Comment: The benefit is that you don't need to write the implementation for each entity. You write the implementation in the `GenericRepository` only and you can re-use it for all other entities. If you have anything more specific you can add it as a method in the corresponding Repository. I hope this helps.

Comment: imho that implementation provide no benefit over using entity framework directly as you expose `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 6):

Generic repositories are worthless. They just do the same thing as entity framework and most of the implementations out there expose `IQueryable<T>`.

So why is that so bad?

The repository pattern is used to create an abstraction between the data source and your code. That abstraction is created to reduce complexity and to reduce coupling between those tiers.

A generic repository might seem to be a good choice at first, but as every entity (root aggregate) have their own unique features you will always have to write custom queries to fetch them.

To solve that, most generic implementations expose `IQueryable<T>`. That is a bad thing since there is no 100% complete Linq to Sql provider (a set of classes which translates the LINQ statement to a SQL statement). Every provider has to resort to custom commands to support eager/lazy loading, support for `IN` sql clause etc.

You always have to be aware of those customizations every time you use the repository through `IQueryable<T>`.

Hence you still have to know about how Entity Framework works. You could therefore use EF directly instead of using a generic repository.

If you truly want to use the repository pattern, please design your code first with all your classes. And THEN create the database. That is, fit the DB after your code and not vice versa. And make sure that your repository is 100% complete abstraction (google for instance `persistance ignorance`)

Comment: +1 If you're going to abstract away the database, then do it fully. Could just get rid of IRepository altogether and have two separate IStudentRepo and ITeacherRepo interfaces.

Comment: The Generic Repository works only when T is a domain object and the repo implementation is always the same i.e Save() means serialize object, Get() means deserialize object. You can say it is a pattern useful for that case only. Used else where it's an anti pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the Generic Repository idea is trying to generalize too much, seperate interfaces are better in my opinion as they provide a more meaningful contract, [this blog](http://www.ben-morris.com/why-the-generic-repository-is-just-a-lazy-anti-pattern) explains it very good, and offers to use the generic repository "behind the scenes".